# Lodash create an array from an array using a value of one character

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

I have an array containing the following,

```
var people = [{
    _id: 0,
    name: 'Joe'
}, {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Jim'
}, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Mary'
}];
```

So with lodash, I want to create an array from `people` where name contains `J` any ideas?

For example:

```
var newPeople = _.filter(people, function(person) {
    return _.contains('J', person.name);
});
```

Or even better:

```
var newPeople = _(people).map(_.unary(_.partialRight(_.contains, 'J', 'name'))).value();
```

Any functional version of the above would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean functional version, you own first implementation is pretty functional and works and "reads" great. Why won't you use that? :)

Comment: Oh Lodash does not have _.contains, that's why .. :).. allright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var newPeople = _.filter(people, function(person) {
    return person.name.indexOf('J') >= 0;
});
```

For your other way of doing it:

```
var contains = function (obj, str, elem) {
    if (obj[elem].indexOf(str) >= 0) {
        return obj;
    }
    return;
}

newPeople = _(people).map(_.unary(_.partialRight(contains, 'J', 'name'))).compact().sortBy('name').value();
```

Comment: How would I sort that?

Comment: `var newPeople = _.chain(people).filter(function(person) {
 return person.name.indexOf('J') >= 0;
}).sortBy('name').value();
` ?

Comment: Anyway I could chain that all together into one assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need lodash for the comparison. For example, this works:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script>
  var people = [{
    _id: 0,
    name: 'Joe'
  }, {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Jim'
  }, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Mary'
  }];
  var newPeople = _.filter(people, function(person) {
    return person.name.indexOf('J') > -1;
  });
  console.log(newPeople);
</script>
```